# Difference between setTextContent() and appendChild(Text)

Tags: java, xml, dom

When creating a XML document what is the difference (if there is any) between these two methods of adding text to an element:

```
Element el = document.createElement("element");
el.setTextContent("This is the text content");
```

and

```
Element el = document.createElement("element");
Text txt = document.createTextNode("This is the text content");
el.appendChild(txt);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the documentation for `Element#setTextContent()`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent%28java.lang.String%29)

> On setting, any possible children this node may have are removed and, if it the new string is not empty or null, replaced by a single Text node containing the string this attribute is set to.

[`Element#appendChild()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) does not remove existing children (except in the case that the specified child is already in the tree). Therefore

```
el.setTextContent("This is the text content")
```

is equivalent to removing all children *before* calling `el.appendChild()`:

```
for(Node n : el.getChildNodes())
{
    el.removeChild(n);
}
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is the text content"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild()`

method adds a node after the last child node of the specified element node.

```
setTextContent()
```

Replace the text content by this one.